# cutting strings onto new lines

Tags: python, string

My string is too long to fit in TkInter, therefore I'm trying to split the list every 15 spaces onto a new line.

so far I have counted the spaces and everytime I get to 15 it adds the string '\n', which should put it on a new line, however it just places it in the string.

How can I fix this?`

```
def stringCutter(movie):
    n = 0
    strings = []
    spaces = 0
    curFilms = db.CurrentFilm(movie)
    tempOverview = curFilms[5]
    for i in tempOverview:
        n += 1
        if i == ' ':
            spaces += 1
            if (spaces % 15)== 0:
                string = tempOverview[:n]
                tempOverview = tempOverview[n:]
                strings.append(string)
                n = 0
                spaces = 0
        if n == len(tempOverview):
            strings.append(tempOverview)
    overview = '\n'.join(strings)
    return overview`
```

curFilms takes lots of movie info and the 5 element is the overview, which is a long string.

I want it to return the overview like this: 
After a global war the seaside kingdom known as the Valley Of The Wind remains

one of the last strongholds on Earth untouched by a poisonous jungle and the powerful

insects that guard it. Led by the courageous Princess Nausicaa the people of the Valley

engage in an epic struggle to restore the bond between humanity and Earth.

Instead of that though, it does this:
After a global war the seaside kingdom known as the Valley Of The Wind remains \none of the last strongholds on Earth untouched by a poisonous jungle and the powerful \ninsects that guard it. Led by the courageous Princess Nausicaa the people of the Valley \nengage in an epic struggle to restore the bond between humanity and Earth.

Comment: Welcome to `StackOverflow[SO]`, please be a bit more specific [when asking question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): What have you tried so far with code example? / What do you expect? / What error do you get?

Comment: I think you already know this, but the `\n` character is a newline character, so this should do what you expect?

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: While your edit helps, it isn't a [mcve]. People should be able to copy your code into a Python shell and run it directly. Your code has an external dependency (`db.CurrentFilm(movie)`) which prevents anyone but you from directly running it (though it wouldn't be all that hard for a *sufficiently interested* reader to mock-up some data). You are more likely to get an answer if you make it so others can easily run your code and thus see the actual problem.

Comment: By the way -- your code works as intended. You see the `'\n'` displayed in the Python shell, but if you e.g. *print* the result of your function call then it displays as intended. The shell is for programmers, not end users. Programmers often need to be able to see the escape characters in the strings, so when it displays a string it does so. It is the distinction between `__repr__` and `__str__` (Google "magic methods in Python") if you don't know what that means).